# MDX - Calculation, based on Dimension Attribute

Tags: mdx

I am trying to use an IIF statement to decide how I will work out a calculation based on a dimension attribute field.

The syntax does not give me any errors however the end result in the browser keeps defaulting to my 'Else' condition.

Let's say I have dimension Product with an attribute Flag

If Flag = ' Y ' I need to calculate something
Else I need to calculate something else

For some reason it keeps defaulting to my else...

Have looked around on the net however the suggestions for other people's concerns were somewhat complex.

Can anyone advise please ?

Answer (score 0):

Worked around this by using a numerical conditional statement to create a measure which I then used as the basis for my workings.

Kindly close
Regards

Answer (score 0):

(I'm guessing this bit) If 'Y' is a member of an attribute hierarchy specified as `[Product].[Flag]` and therefore defined as this:

```
[Product].[Flag].[Flag].&[Y]
```

Then to use inside an IIF I'd use the `IS` operator like this

```
[Measures].[blahblah] AS
  IIF(
    [Product].[Flag].CURRENTMEMBER
            IS [Product].[Flag].[Flag].&[Y]
    , 'HELLO'
    , 'WORLD'
  )
```